# Como remover o espaço entre uma linha e outra de cards no Bootstrap4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite.

Estou usando o Bootstrap4 no meu projeto Django, porém, como no print a seguir, há um espaço entre os cards(marquei com um x), por conta de seu tamanho diferente. Gostaria que as imagens abaixo se encaixassem naturalmente(como ocorre no Pinterest, por exemplo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estive dando uma olhada na documentação básica do Bootstrap mas não consegui encontrar uma solução adequada para eliminar esse espaço. Para criar essa página eu estou me guiando pelo exemplo [Album](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/). Segue o código que tenho agora, e que gera aquele printscreen:

```
{% for l in lores %}
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                          <div>
                            <a href="{% url 'lore_detail' pk=l.pk %}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{l.image.url}}"></a>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p class="card-text">{{ l.title }}</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  {% endfor %}
```

Esse for é do meu Django, e está funcionando corretamente (desculpem a identação, na cópia para cá ficou esquisito.)

Comment: Com bootstrap nativo vc não vai conseguir fazer eles se encaixarem, o máximo que vc vai conseguir e deixar todas com a mesma altura, assim não fica espaço vazio, mas todos ficam da mesma altura. Se quiser que eles se encaixem, procure sobre mansori layout que acho que pode ser o que vc quer

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo sozinho, vou deixar registrado. Espero que seja útil.

A resposta está na documentação, no trecho que fala sobre os Cards. Funciona de forma parecida com o masonry que recomendaram nos comentários. Porem, é uma solução utilizando o próprio bootstrap.

Basta colocar o meu for entre uma [div card columns](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/card/#colunas-de-cards):

```
<div class="card-columns">
    {% for l in lores %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```